# How to get refresh token and expiresInSeconds from flutter Google Sign In plugin

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement the Google Sign In into my flutter application, but i'm missing some information : 
- refresh Token
- ExpiresInSeconds.

How are you able to get this information?

```
GoogleSignIn _googlSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',

]);

print('Google user ==>');
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googlSignIn.signIn();
print(googleUser.id); //account_uid
print(googleUser.email);
print(googleUser.authHeaders);
print(googleUser.displayName); //display_name
print(googleUser.photoUrl); //image_url

print('Google Auth ==>');
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
print(googleAuth.accessToken);
print(googleAuth.hashCode);
print(googleAuth.idToken);
```

I need to specify the following items as well,

include_granted_scopes : true
access_type: offline

Comment: you need to request offline access to get a refresh token

Comment: Yes, but I can't find how with the Google Sign In Package? https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in

Comment: may i ask why you need one?  This is signin you only need a refresh token if you want to access a users data when they are not signed in.  This is also flutter so i am assuming a mobile app.  THe user is signed in why need a refresh token?

Comment: I need this refresh token, because i'm processing some date where I need the tokens for.

Comment: this is needed because you cant force a user to keep on signing in whenever the app is opened. that is bad ui flow. the moment the user is signed in, it should not show him the login page anymore so when access token expires, it is needed to refresh that token.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a refresh token is yet to be supported by the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) plugin. A workaround was posted in this [issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45847#issuecomment-1090337228). A refresh token can be manually generated by sending out a request to [Identity Platform API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithIdp).